# Stsd box could not be found when using libstreaming on Google Glass

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4, rtsp, google-glass

I am trying to stream live camera video from android device to a webpage. Currently I used [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library to stream camera video to VLC player.

When I deployed the project on Nexus 5 device it is working fine and I can see camera video streaming in VLC player. But when I tried to deploy same code in Google Glass it is throwing me an error saying "**Error: stsd box could not be found**"

This error comes from the [MP4Parser.java](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/issues/attachmentText?id=61&aid=610000000&name=MP4Parser.java&token=xAAdDwJZXKX00McuC59WT5nKqC0:1392809660990) file on **line number 63**.

```
public StsdBox getStsdBox() throws IOException {
                try {
                        return new StsdBox(fis,getBoxPos("/moov/trak/mdia/minf/stbl/stsd"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new IOException("Error: stsd box could not be found");
                }
        }
```

Kindly help me if anybody is having any idea on this issue.

Thank You, 
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in recent commit and I could able to successfully stream from Google Glass to a Webpage.

http://www.ohloh.net/p/libstreaming-examples/commits/318839206

Answer (score 0):

I think it was libstream bug, that was solved in last commit (17 days ago).